# a lecture that guides students to re-create git

Tags: git

A few years ago I visited a university (very likely an US university) lecture website that teaches perhaps file system or version control system (I'm really unsure here), which gradually lead students to build a simplified git. Can someone who has seen something similar tell me what lecture is it?

(I have been searching using varied keywords but got nothing.)

Comment: This?  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/boost-programming-skills-read-git-code/amp/

Comment: @Rusi no, I remember it was an university lecture.

Comment: IIRC, CMU does a big git-creation lab, though I can't find any links.  ("git" is such a popular search term!)

Comment: Not a university lecture, but [build your own git](https://github.com/danistefanovic/build-your-own-x#build-your-own-git) has a handful of useful resources.

Comment: I am guessing that you are asking about the beautifully elegant internals of `git`, not the ugly user interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [retroactive data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_data_structure).

These are used with Git ([ref](https://thescipub.com/pdf/jcssp.2020.906.915.pdf))

The MIT Open Courseware for [Advanced Data Structures](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-851-advanced-data-structures-spring-2012/index.htm) by Prof. Erik Demaine teaches this in [Session 2: Retroactive Data Structures](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-851-advanced-data-structures-spring-2012/lecture-videos/session-2-retroactive-data-structures/)

HTH

Comment: From the description on that wikipedia page (and from the article you linked to as well), it sounds like git uses persistent data structures rather than retroactive.  Github at least uses blobs, which are immutable.

Comment: @BenI. While I am not Git Jedi I do recall that deep down in Git one can retroactively change a commit, thus retroactive instead of persistent. I don't have the time at present to research this but the 8-ball says `sounds reasonable`

Comment: No, no, I mean that the reference you linked to states outright that it's persistent.